# GSON-based DSL causing a NPE

Tags: kotlin, gson, dsl

I've been trying to create a Kotlin DSL for creating GSON JsonObjects with a JSON-like syntax. My builder looks like this

```
import com.google.gson.JsonArray
import com.google.gson.JsonElement
import com.google.gson.JsonObject
import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive

class JsonBuilder(builder: JsonBuilder.() -> Unit) {
    init {
        builder()
    }

    val result = JsonObject()

    infix fun String.to(property: Number) = result.addProperty(this, property)
    infix fun String.to(property: Char) = result.addProperty(this, property)
    infix fun String.to(property: Boolean) = result.addProperty(this, property)
    infix fun String.to(property: String) = result.addProperty(this, property)
    infix fun String.to(property: JsonElement) = result.add(this, property)
    infix fun String.to(properties: Collection<JsonElement>) {
        val arr = JsonArray()
        properties.forEach(arr::add)
        result.add(this, arr)
    }
    operator fun String.invoke(builder: JsonObject.() -> Unit) {
        val obj = JsonObject()
        obj.builder()
        result.add(this, obj)
    }
}

fun json(builder: JsonBuilder.() -> Unit) = JsonBuilder(builder).result
```

And my test looks like this

```
fun main() {
    val json = json {
        "name" to "value"
        "obj" {
            "int" to 1
        }
        "true" to true
    }
    println(json)
}
```

However, upon execution it causes a NullPointerException pointing to the first String extension function used, which I don't find very descriptive as I don't see anything being nullable up to that point. Moreover, I don't see how it really differs from the regular execution which of course doesn't cause a NPE.

```
    val json = JsonObject()
    json.addProperty("name", "value")
    val obj = JsonObject()
    obj.addProperty("int", 1)
    json.add("obj", obj)
    json.addProperty("true", true)
```

My question is what's exactly causing the exception (and how to prevent it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you've specified the initialiser block earlier than the result object, causing it to be null when you come to use it - this can be visualised by the following (decompiled output of your code).

```
   public JsonBuilder(@NotNull Function1 builder) {
         Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(builder, "builder");
         super();
         builder.invoke(this);
         this.result = new JsonObject();
   }
```

Therefore, the solution is to move the declaration and initialisation of result earlier than the initialiser block.

```
class JsonBuilder(builder: JsonBuilder.() -> Unit) {
    val result = JsonObject()

    init {
        builder()
    }

    // ...
}
```

And the result is now...

```
{"name":"value","int":1,"obj":{},"true":true}
```

EDIT: You'll also want to allow chaining with your DSL, and fix a bug you currently have.

```
    operator fun String.invoke(builder: JsonBuilder.() -> Unit) {
        val obj = JsonBuilder(builder).result
        result.add(this, obj)
    }
```

Which produces the correct result of

```
{"name":"value","obj":{"int":1},"true":true}
```

Comment: Oh. Thanks! I wasn't aware that that order mattered in Kotlin.